# Which is a production-ready version of ChronicleMap?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-map

I want to play a bit with ChronicleMap and a bit confused which version should I use in production.

`1.*` looks like 'released' one, `2.*` looks like in alpha stage. I would use release version but from my understanding current documentation refers features from an alpha version.
I.e. I don't see `OffHeapUpdatableChronicleMapBuilder` in `1.0.2`. Since it is a 'official' documentation I can think that `2.*` can be used in production as well. Can it?

PS Environment - java 8, 64 bit windows for dev, linux in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chronicle Map 2.x is the version you should be considering.
It is in beta now, with no significant enhancements planned, only bug fixes.

The beta version is suitable for development and the API won't change significantly before the release.

How long it is a beta release depends on how many bugs are reported. Of course we are hoping this will be a week or two.

The first production quality release will be 2.1.